# How to handle 400(Bad Request) error in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, https

I want to handle 400 error in rails, actually I have to display newsletters in my website and some of the links in the newsletters have relative path, instead of absolute path, so the link that is begin generated is http://testapp.com/newsletters/6500/%%view_email_url%%, and because of this I am getting 400 error, I have handled the error for all the newsletters, but in the google have indexed some of the pages with this format.

So if any can help me in resolving this issue, I want to handle 400 error in rails.

There is one more thing that I want to share with you, in the UI, I am getting **Bad request** and in the logs I am getting **!!invalid request**, I just want to know can I handle 400(bad request) error in rails, or it has to do with app server or web server.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have a look at the "14.2 rescue_from" section in http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html

Comment: @MaxWilliams, I really appreciate for your help, but I am not getting any request to my controllers,I have added debugger to it, but request is going to any of the controller.

Comment: @MaxWilliams yeah, so I was looking at solutions about handling 400 error, like which middle layer of rails handle 400 error, still no success

Comment: Sounds like you just need to fix the links so that they have the proper url though.

Comment: For me problem, is google has indexed some of the links with this url, so I have to find some way out from this.

Comment: @railsman Did you find any solution for this issue?